# How to use paranoid in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

I am a newbie to Sequelize if I want to delete an entry I will not delete directly I have a separate field to make it active and inactive. So I want to have a deteledAT field to update automatically while deleting an entry. Is there any way I can do with paranoid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your model add:

```
  paranoid: true,
  timestamps: true,
```

Little example:

```
sequelize.define(
    'example',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        defaultValue: sequelize.literal('uuid_generate_v1()'),
      }
    },
    {
      tableName: 'example',
      createdAt: 'created_at',
      updatedAt: 'updated_at',
      deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
      paranoid: true,
      timestamps: true,
    },
  );
```

So, we'll get `example` table with 4 colums (id, created_at, updated_at, deletedAt) and when you call `destroy` method sequeslize insert date in `deletedAt` column and for select (findOne, findAll etc) automatically ignore all rows when deletedAt is not null

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful

Comment: It does not work for me. I don't have `deteledAT` column created for me by sequelize.

Comment: OP may have typo'd 'deletedAt' as  'deteledAT'.  It caused me to look again

Comment: not work , i dunno why ,version : "sequelize": "^6.6.5"