# deletedAt column not found while making a simple select

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm using mysql on a database that doesn't have a deletedAt column, on the examples i've seen it should appear after turning timestamps and paranoid to true. what am i missing?

code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlState: '42S22',
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Movie.deletedAt' in 'field list'",

Comment: I don't know sequelize, but from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54688296/17389 it looks like you need to specify what column name to use for deletedAt

Comment: already tried it, and it still doesnt create the column :c

Comment: yes, that's what I meant; it looks like it does not create the column for you, you have to create it and tell it the name you gave it